# Using web pages as a data source of an android project

Tags: android

I'm working on a tv guide android project that I want to take updated program guides of different TV channels from their web sites. How can I access and use these program guide informations on my project in the optimized way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from specified pages you can download those pages, and then parse them.

Here is a sample AsyncTask which does this staff in background and after download finished, you can webpage:

```
public class DownloadManager extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {

    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /**
     * @param context
     *            of application
     * @param progressDialog
     *            which you want to show the download progress.
     */
    public DownloadManager(Context context, ProgressDialog progressDialog,        DownloadCallbackListener downloadListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
        String sUrl = args[0];
        String fileName = args[1];

        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            int contentLenght = connection.getContentLength();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];

            InputStream inStream = connection.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = new FileHelper(fileName).getFileOutputStream();
            int readCount = 0;
            int totalRead = 0;
            int failurTryCount = 0;

            boolean downloadFinished = true;
            while ((readCount = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                try {
                    if (failurTryCount > 5) {
                        downloadFinished = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    downloadFinished = true;
                    output.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                    output.flush();
                    totalRead += readCount;
                    onProgressUpdate(totalRead * 100 / contentLenght);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    ++failurTryCount;
                }
            }
            return downloadFinished ? 0 : -4;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -2;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -3;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        if (result == 0) {
            // progressDialog.dismiss();
        } 
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

But if those websites have webservices to consume, It would be better choice to use them up.

Comment: I've read sth about "crawl". Do you know sth about this? Can this method help to my problem?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the answer is no. because your problem is about view a part of a page (if I understand correctly). I think you should write your own code to get your desired part.